# JSP, JSTL получение объекта из сессии

Tags: jstl, jsp, java

Имеется такой код:

```
<c:set var="user" value="${sessionScope.user}"/>
```

Дальше хочу получить его имя, скажем, так:

```
${user.name}
```

но среда разработки не понимает что это мой объект и говорит исправь ошибку. Вопрос: Как задать тип переменной? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это зависит от IDE. Некоторые IDE позволяют сделать специальный комментарий, который подскажет, какого типа ваш объект.

С другой стороны, обычно в сессию объекты попадают из уровню контроллера. В таком случае, непонятно: откуда взялся c:set ? Вы изначально неверно делаете: Нет смысла заносить что-то в сессию из JSP на этапе генерирования документа. Всё должно быть уже заготовлено заранее. При таком раскладе при использовании на странице вы используете jsp:useBean, где вы явно указываете type и scope.

Так что ответ прост: чтобы решить проблему надо сделать по-другому.